# tdlib: GetBasicGroupFullInfo returns "Group not found" error

Tags: java, telegram, tdlib

I want to get all users (user id and username) from group in Telegram. I use the [tdlib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib). ID of group I receive by method [getChats](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1get_chats.html). When I pass received ID to method [GetBasicGroupFullInfo](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1get_basic_group_full_info.html) - I got a response with error:

```
Error {
  code = 6
  message = "Group not found"
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? And how to get user id and username of all users from telegram group?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found out TDLIB had to "cache" the basic group before getting the full info. So what I did is: first, call getBasicGroup (even if you ignore the result) then you can call getBasicGroupFullInfo.